# Packages not appearing in proget feed

Tags: nuget, nuget-server, proget

I am using proget to upload packages, I am manually uploading from disk, but when I go to check if the package exists in the feed it isn't there. When I logon to the server which is hosting proget and go to the PackagesRootPath I can see the package is indeed on the server!

Any ideas why it's not showing up in the feed?

p.s. I have restarted the website/application pool and ProGet service and still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm seeing this same functionality from our ProGet site as well.  Are you running self-hosted or IIS-hosted version?  We have an IIS-hosted version in our setup and have been noticing this issue since a manual shutdown of the server.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not seeing any packages in the web application (and you've verified that they are, in fact, in the right place on disk), this means that the packages aren't getting indexed by the ProGet Service.

Since you've already restarted the ProGet web service, it's likely a problem with the individual package.

Check to see if there are "indexing errors" in the admin section; this will give some insight into what the problem might be. Often times, the file name does not match the package name/version; this is a requirement. If you're package is named MyFoo and is version 3.0.1, it must be MyFoo.3.0.1.nupkg and have an appropriately named MyFoo.nuspec within it.

If there are no errors logged, then you can try to run the service interactively. Simply stop the Windows service, then run the .exe file and select the appropriate option to run.

Another option to verify that the indexing is working OK is to pull a package from a remote connector (like JQuery or something), then drop that package in another feed (that doesn't use a connector).

Comment: I was able to have the **INEDOPROGETSVC** windows service restarted which fixed the issue of not indexing our uploaded NuGet packages.  I'm not really sure what caused this service to stop working but we were not receiving any error messages.